# How can I use only the views in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

By this I mean I don't want to use the other modules.  I have on object that holds all of what would be the model/collection data.  I also have a working Backbone View.

I know there are many ways to do this, but I'm asking which is the best or which is the standard way to do this?

Should I just pass it in through the constructor as an object literal property?

This is the use case:

```
somefunction: function (data_object)  {

    // create FeedView here with data_object

    new FeedView({data: data_object});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using models is strange, but anyway, if it's what you wanna do, this is the way.

Then in your view, inside the render method, just do something like this.

```
initialize: function(options){
    this.data = options.data;
},
render: function(){
    var tpl = _.template(this.template);
    this.$el.html(tpl(JSON.stringify(this.data))); // If you use the underscore templating
}
```

Comment: no you can't pass it in through the constructor unless you use a list of "white listed" keys.

Comment: Well, i did something like that a long ago. But google pointed it out too, so you're right. I changed my answer. This sould be more accurate.